# PHP check if variable is smaller than previous item in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need a way to check if there are events that overlap each other. So I made an array with the start and end hour of every event. It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 0930
            [end] => 1200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1000
            [end] => 1230
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1300
            [end] => 1530
        )

)
```

This is what I've tried to check if there are events that overlap:

```
if ( $orders->have_posts() ):
        while ($orders->have_posts()) : $orders->the_post(); 
          foreach($order as $o){
            $start = $o['start'];
            $end = $o['end'];
            $attractieID = $o['attractie']->ID;

            foreach($order as $key => $attractieID){
                $slots[] = array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
                if($start < $end){
                   //overlap
                }else{
                   //no overlap
                }
            }
          }
        endwhile; 
endif;
```

But this will always give true since I am checking the start and end date of the same item in my array.

I need to way to compare the start value of the current array item and the end value of the previous array item

Anyone knows if this is even possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't start the body of `if` with `{` and end it with `endif`.

Comment: @Barmar this is just a typo with copying my code

Comment: @FrankLucas - Thing about copying code is, it doesn't produce typos. Give actual code.

Comment: @Pamblam there's a lot of other stuff in my loop that is unrelevant to the question why should I copy it aswel?

Comment: copy + delete doesn't produce typos either.... copy + re-write will not only produce typs but will make it difficult for people to answer if one of you "typos" obscures the issue. don't re-write your code just for SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Start looping at index 1, and compare the start time of the current event with the end of the event with index-1.

```
$count = count($order);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($order[$i]['start'] < $order[$i-1]['end']) {
        // overlap
    } else {   
        // no overlap
    }
}
```

If you want to do this while also copying from `$order` to `slots`, you can use a variable to hold the end time from the previous iteration.

```
  $prevEnd = null;
  foreach($order as $o){
    $start = $o['start'];
    $end = $o['end'];
    $attractieID = $o['attractie']->ID;

    $slots[] = array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
    if($prevEnd !== null && $start < $prevEnd){
       //overlap
    }else{
       //no overlap
    }
    $prevEnd = $end;
  }
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/zTRi5Z)

Comment: What does that have to do with checking for overlap?

Comment: Because my start and end values are stored in my slots array

Comment: Aren't they stored in the `$order` array?

Comment: Yes but I need to do a check based on the attractie id see the `$attractieID = $o['attractie']->ID;` in OP

Comment: In an order you can have multimple events(attracties) every attractie has a start and end value. And I need to check for every event(attractie) if there are overlapping events(attracties)

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do the check while also copying from `$order` to `$slots`.

Comment: I've tried your code and it goes to the else everytime

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what I am trying to do

Comment: Fixed. There's no need for the nested loops.

Comment: I get all my orders and loop over them. Inside every order there is an other array with the attracties, every attractie has a start and end value. I need to check the start value with end value of the previous attractie

Comment: That's exactly what my code does. `$prevEnd` is the end value of the previous attractie, so `$start < $prevEnd` compares this start value with the previous end value.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, unfortunately

Comment: I've started a new question explaining my situation better, check it out if you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711431/wordpress-php-loop-over-cpt-comparing-values-to-previous-item-in-array

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal `for` loop. And, to be sure everything is right, sort the array before checking it (if you are sure it is gona be sorted, you can skip that part)

```
$sortedOrders = usort($order, function($a, $b)
{
    $aStart = $a['start'];
    $bStart = $b['start'];

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;  
});

$count = count($sortedOrders);
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    if($sortedOrders[$i - 1]['end'] > $sortedOrders[$i]['start'])
    {
        // Handle overlap
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, with a for loop instead of foreach:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($order);i++){
  $slots[] = array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
   if($order[$i+1]){
     if($order[$i]['start'] < $order[$i+1]['end']{
       //overklap
     }else{
      //no overlap
     }
   }
```