# WordPress php loop over CPT comparing values to previous item in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I query all my orders and loop over them 1 bye 1 and this is what the print looks like: (only copied 1 order) This is the dump of 1 `$order`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attractie] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 41
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2016-02-29 14:30:33
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2016-02-29 14:30:33
                    [post_content] => Content
                    [post_title] => Title
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => post-name
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => attracties
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [start] => 0930
            [end] => 1200
            [personen] => 8
        )

)
```

Now my goal is to check the `start` and `end` hours of every `attractie` in an order to see if there are attracties overlapping each other an order can have multiple `attracties`.

So here's what I've tried but I always get the result `no overlap`.

```
if ( $orders->have_posts() ){
        while ($orders->have_posts()) : $orders->the_post(); 
            $order = get_field('field_56e6a0f52ce6b');
            $prevEnd = null;
            $found_overlap = false;
            foreach($order as $o){
                $attractie = $o['attractie']->post_title;
                $start = $o['start'];
                $end = $o['end'];

                if($prevEnd !== null && $start < $prevEnd){
                   $found_overlap = true;
                }

                if ($found_overlap) {
                    echo "overlap\n";
                } else {
                    echo "no overlap\n";
                }

                $prevEnd = $end;
            }

        endwhile; 
}
```

Comment: Include more code. I would like to see where that $order come from.

Comment: @chba the result of $order is what I posted in OP the array is the dump of $order

Comment: Cool, but I cannot see that in code. Besides, your curly brackets looks a bit off. You start if with bracket and end with endif; ? Looks weird to me. Besides, why $order is singular if you are foreach-ing it? Are there more loops that surrounds this code? Btw, there are no need to  $orders->have_posts() in if and one more time at while loop. Using it at while is enough!

Comment: @chba I updated OP check it out if you want

Comment: Print out $start and $prevEnd before that if statement and check if you actually get expected dates.

Comment: @chba I do get the $start hour but not the $prevEnd one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109511/discussion-between-frank-lucas-and-chba).